# How can I separate gridview elements?

Tags: android

I have 4x4 sudoku game that is built using gridview. Each square is an Image View.

Now I want to make separation lines like in this picture:
[image: http://i.imgur.com/cMyJyqk.png]

I know I can add images with lines for each element but it would be too much work. Is there easier way of doing it?

Comment: Add some padding to the items (i.e.: 2dp). So, letting show the background color, which gives you the vertical and horizontal "dividers".

Answer (score 0):

Please set background of row in xml with help of drawable

like this-

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle" >

    <solid android:color="@color/white" />

    <stroke
        android:width="1dp"
        android:color="@color/line" />

</shape>
```

set background of row in xml

Comment: Won't it set lines for every spacing that I have? I want to achieve to cross in the middle like I have drawn.